# Why can not I use `new [ ]` with smart_pointers?

Tags: c++11, stl, smart-pointers

Why can not I use `new [ ]` with smart_pointers?

Actually I can not understand this piece of text.

> Caution You should use an auto_prt or shared_ptr object only for
>   memory allocated by new, not for memory allocated by new []. You
>   should not use auto_ptr, shared_ptr,orunique_ptr for memory not
>   allocated via new or, in the case of unique_ptr, via new or new[].

Comment: Actually, you should not use `auto_ptr` at all, it's deprecated and will be removed in the next standard. Also, [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) have a specialization for arrays using `new[]`, see the [this `operator[]` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) for an example on how to use it.

Comment: it would be easier to understand with an example how to do and how not to do

Comment: I'm not sure about `shared_ptr` (without looking it up, rarely using it), but `unique_ptr` is **most definitively** specialized for arrays, and works fine (well-defined).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why can not I use `new[]` with smart pointers?*

In general you can, but that smart pointer must be aware of the fact that it stores a dynamically allocated array, not a single object. This is because objects allocated with operator `new[]` should be deallocated with operator `delete[]`, *not* `delete`. How can a smart pointer know which operator should be applied?

The distinction is made by providing a specialization of smart pointer class templates for array types, like it is currently done in [`std::unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int);      // will call delete
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[5]); // will call delete[]
                   ↑↑
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7129a400f1da35bc)

However, that syntax does not (yet) apply to all smart pointer types available in the Standard Library.

For comparison, the [Boost Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) library provides separate class templates for storing pointers to dynamically allocated arrays:

```
boost::shared_array<int> arr1(new int[5]); // will call delete[]
//            ~~~~^
boost::scoped_array<int> arr2(new int[5]); // will call delete[]
//            ~~~~^
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e7943544071b708)

---

> *You should use an `auto_ptr` or `shared_ptr` object only for memory allocated by `new`, not for memory allocated by `new []`.*

[`std::auto_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr)(† 2017)<sup>1</sup> applies a plain `delete` operator to a pointer it stores, and there is no way to change that behavior. As such, storing a pointer to an array is not an option.

As far as [`std::shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is concerned, by default it does the same (calls operator `delete`). To change that behavior, and properly deallocate a memory area of a stored array, you could use a custom deleter, like [`std::default_delete<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete):

```
std::shared_ptr<int> arr(new int[5], std::default_delete<int[]>{});
                                                            ↑↑
```

or some other provided by yourself:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> arr(new int[5], [](int* ptr) { delete[] ptr; } );
//                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9602bafb2b6ade1)

However, a missing specialization for `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` implies no `operator[]` that could let you easily access the elements of a stored array, which leads to unintuitive syntax like `arr.get()[0]`.

With proposal [N4077](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4077.html) introduced, there **will be** a specialization for array type pointers:

```
std::shared_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[5]); // will call delete[]
                   ↑↑
```

---

> *You should not use `auto_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, or `unique_ptr` for memory not allocated via `new` or, in the case of `unique_ptr`, via `new` or `new[]`.*

This excerpt simply states that one should not construct a smart pointer from a pointer to an object that was not allocated dynamically, as (by default) it would result in calling `delete` on something that was not allocated with `new` (ditto `new[]`/`delete[]`).

---

> *What is the difference between `unique_ptr<double[]> p1(new double[2]);`, `unique_ptr<double> p2(new double[2]);`,  `unique_ptr<double[]> p3(new double(2));` ?*

1. `std::unique_ptr<double[]> p1(new double[2]);`

**OK**: Constructs a `unique_ptr` from (and takes ownership of) a pointer to an *array* of two `double`s. It will call `delete[]` to deallocate the memory pointed.

2. `std::unique_ptr<double> p2(new double[2]);`

**Wrong**: Constructs a `unique_ptr` from (and takes ownership of) a pointer to an *array* of two `double`s. It will call `delete` (!) to deallocate the memory pointed. (possibly undefined behavior - a mismatch between `new[]` and `delete`).

3. `std::unique_ptr<double[]> p3(new double(2));`

**Wrong**: Constructs a `unique_ptr` from (and takes ownership of) a pointer to a *single* `double` initialized to value `2`. It will call `delete[]` (!) to deallocate the memory pointed. (possibly undefined behavior - a mismatch between `new` and `delete[]`).

---

<sup>1</sup> `std::auto_ptr<T>` is deemed deprecated in favor of `std::unique_ptr<T>` since C++11, and will be removed from the Standard Library in C++1z according to [N4168](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4168).

Comment: @ Piotr Skotnicki Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Examples:**

```
#include <memory>

int
main()
{
    auto p1 = std::unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[3]};  // C++11
    auto p2 = std::shared_ptr<char>{new char[3], [](char* p) {delete [] p;}}; // C++11
    auto p3 = std::make_unique<char[]>(3);           // C++14
}
```

The first and second are good for C++11 and forward.  The 3rd was introduced in C++14.  The first and third represent unique ownership of the new, and the second has shared ownership of the new.